# Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, npm, webpack, permission-denied

Following error while executing `webpack` as `jenkins` job.

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'dist/assets'

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-33-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "rimraf" "--" "dist"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! rimraf: `rimraf "dist"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is a permissions issue, was fixed by giving `jenkins` full access rights to the concerned folder.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18414606/452708)

Similar issue also reported for [NodeJS plugin npm install without root permissions](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33698)

[image]